# Fading background images automaticly in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, animation, uiimage, fading

Im trying to fade several background images in xcode. They are animated but not fading, see code below:

```
animationgirl.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:

                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl1.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl2.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl3.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl4.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl5.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl6.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl7.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl8.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl9.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl10.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl11.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl12.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl13.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"girl14.png"],nil];

[animationgirl setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
animationgirl.animationDuration = 1.8;
[animationgirl startAnimating];
```

Comment: What you expect this code should do ? you did not change any properties of your images.

Comment: please ,clear your question?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question :) This code is for the animation, it'w working fine, but instead of direct show the next image, I want this in a fading option. Can this be done with this code?

Comment: Please add the more code, where you do image sequence animation.

Comment: There is no sequence, sorry im pretty new to iOS development. This code is hooked on IBOutlet UIImageView *animationgirl; Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `animationImages` does not support an additional fade-in/fade-out effect when transitioning between images.

What you can do is creating a `CAKeyframeAnimation` and provide it with the array of images you are trying to animate, e.g.:

```
    NSArray* contents = <NSArray of UIImages>;

    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    [animation setCalculationMode:kCAAnimationLinear];
    [animation setDuration:contentsAnimationDuration];
    [animation setRepeatCount:HUGE_VALF];
    [animation setValues:contents];        

    [self.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"contents"];
```

In order to use Core Animation, you have to link the Quartz framework and include the relevant header file.

You could also you a [category on CALayer I wrote for this purpose](https://github.com/sdesimone/iOSSnippets/blob/master/SDSCategories/CALayer+SDSContentsAnimation.m).